# php date format question

Tags: php

i've got code

```
$dss='2011 04 28 10:00:45';
echo date('Y', strtotime($dss));
```

it display 1970- why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [strtotime() & date() weired behaviour when converting date in to same format as it was before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101605/strtotime-date-weired-behaviour-when-converting-date-in-to-same-format-as-i)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> it display 1970- why?

Becuase the format `YYYY MM DD HH:MM:SS` isn't one of the [formats that `strtotime` accepts](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).  In particular, it's failing to find a [valid date string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

If you're using PHP 5.3 or better, look at [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), which takes a `date`-formatted string and creates a new DateTime object based on that format.

If you're stuck on a lower version of PHP, your "best" choice is the clunky [`strptime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php).

Or you can just stick dashes between the `YYYY` and `MM` and then between the `MM` and the `DD`, yielding `YYYY-MM-DD`, a perfectly cromulent format.

Comment: so how can i convert this string to date?

Comment: @kusanagi, I have updated my answer with a few ways to deal with the string.

Answer (score 2):

As Charles says it's not a valid date format. This should reformat it:

```
$dss = preg_replace('/^(\d+) (\d+) (.+)$/i', '$1-$2-$3', $dss);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong answer before...was -1 worthy...I'm now climbing backwards onto the donkey, putting the pail on my head, and leaving town.

Comment: Where did the 'Delete' link go?  Read too quickly and now regret it :/

Comment: @Steve, I can't find one for my own answer either.  Weird.  Maybe you can edit your answer into correctness?  (Hint: On error, `strtotime` returns either `false` or -1 based on the PHP version being used.)

Comment: Yes, was, and is, Weird.  Thanks for the tip though! Taken, with some self-deprecating flippancy.

Comment: @Steve, [I filed a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89083/unable-to-delete-own-answers-the-delete-link-is-gone), looks like it'll be fixed very soon (moments?)

Comment: Great, thanks.  And to the -1 person, cheers on the reversal :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want only the year from this sting. You can simply do this:

```
$dss='2011 04 28 10:00:45';
echo substr($dss, 0, 5);
```